# How to connect to our own dedicated server using photon networking in unity?(Self-hosted)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, self-hosting, photon

In below script am trying to connect my game with my own server. But every time I get an error like

> -(JoinRandomRoom failed. Client is on MasterServer (must be Master Server for matchmaking) but not ready for operations (State: ConnectingToMasterServer). Wait for callback: OnJoinedLobby or OnConnectedToMaster.)

please check my below script and check what is wrong.

```
[SerializeField] private GameObject FindOppenentTxt = null;
[SerializeField] private GameObject waitingStatusPanel = null;
[SerializeField] private Text waitingStatusText = null;

private bool isConnnecting = false;

[SerializeField]
private const string GameVersion = "1.1";

private const int maxPlayer = 2;

private string masterServerAddress = "**********";
private int port = 7777;
private string appID = "*************7d645e794534";

private void Awake()
{
    PhotonNetwork.AutomaticallySyncScene = true;
}

private void strart()
{
    PhotonNetwork.SendRate = 20;
    PhotonNetwork.SerializationRate = 5;
    PhotonNetwork.ConnectToMaster(masterServerAddress, port, appID);
    //PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
}

public void FindOpponent()
{
    isConnnecting = true;
    FindOppenentTxt.SetActive(false);
    waitingStatusPanel.SetActive(true);
    waitingStatusText.text = "Searching...";

    if(PhotonNetwork.IsConnected)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
        Debug.Log("findingRoom");
    }
    else
    {
        //PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, new RoomOptions { MaxPlayers = maxPlayer });
        Debug.Log("creatingRoom");
        PhotonNetwork.GameVersion = GameVersion;
        //PhotonNetwork.ConnectUsingSettings();
        PhotonNetwork.ConnectToMaster(masterServerAddress, port, appID);
        Debug.Log(PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom);
    }
}

public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    if(isConnnecting)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
        Debug.Log("Server IP: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);
    }
}

public override void OnDisconnected(DisconnectCause cause)
{
    waitingStatusPanel.SetActive(false);
    FindOppenentTxt.SetActive(true);
    Debug.Log("disconnected");
}

public override void OnJoinRandomFailed(short returnCode, string message)
{
    Debug.Log("There are no clients");
    PhotonNetwork.CreateRoom(null, new RoomOptions { MaxPlayers = maxPlayer });
}

public override void OnJoinedRoom()
{
    Debug.Log("Joined a room ssuccessfully");
    int playerCount = PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount;
    if(playerCount != maxPlayer)
    {
        waitingStatusText.text = "waiting for an opponent";
    }
    else
    {
        waitingStatusText.text = "Opponent Found...please wait..";
    }
}

public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    if (PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.PlayerCount == maxPlayer)
    {
        PhotonNetwork.CurrentRoom.IsOpen = false;
        waitingStatusText.text = "opponent in room";

        PhotonNetwork.LoadLevel("MainScene");
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you verified that your self-hosted Photon server is actually running? Can the test-client connect to it? Can a Unity Client, that runs on the same machine as the server, connect to it? Have you configured the firewall and router of your server machine, to let incoming connections on the specified port and protocol through? Have you configured the server to actually listen for incoming connections on the specified non-default port?

Comment: Are you using Photon Server v4 or v5?
With v5 the server type to connect to should be the name server, not the master server. The master server is the correct server type for v4, though.

Did you follow the guide at https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/server/current/getting-started/photon-server-in-5min#loadbalancing_instance?

Answer (score 0):

First of all `strart` should probably rather be [`Start`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Start.html) .... otherwise it is just never called.

---

And then afaik in order to be able to join / create a room you first have to be in a **Lobby**!

So you should use [`PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby()`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#abc47482d1c2d5228b8f6bc44bafccf30) (or also [`PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby(TypedLobby)`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_photon_network.html#a9ec79536a86310680b2f498dd0c1fc65)) and then listen to [`MonoBehaviourPunCallbacks.OnJoinedLobby`](https://doc-api.photonengine.com/en/pun/v2/class_photon_1_1_pun_1_1_mono_behaviour_pun_callbacks.html#aab1c0bf03b29543c85fba6f116da6986) like e.g.

```
public override void OnConnectedToMaster()
{
    Debug.Log("Server IP: " + PhotonNetwork.ServerAddress);

    if(isConnnecting)
    {
        Debug.Log("joining default lobby ...");
        PhotonNetwork.JoinLobby();
    }
}

public override void OnJoinedLobby()
{
    Debug.Log("Joined Lobby!");

    Debug.Log("Trying to join random room ...")
    PhotonNetwork.JoinRandomRoom();
}
```

See also [Matchmaking and Lobby](https://doc.photonengine.com/en-us/realtime/current/lobby-and-matchmaking/matchmaking-and-lobby)

Comment: I've followed your statements and I've followed all the doc but still am not able to find my solution. Do you have any tutorials or steps or anything so that I can easily understand and can connect  to my game to my own server.

Comment: My only Goal is connect to my own server using IP address and port. Also when I try to connect using photon server its working fine. when I put these IP address and Port. its not working.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Clients are **NOT** required to be inside a lobby to be able to join a room. Joining random rooms works fine without being inside a lobby. Bein inside a lobby is only required to get room list events that automatically update the local list of available rooms. However one can also manually just call a GetRoomList operation to receive room list updates outside of lobbies.

Comment: @Kaiserludi hi, thanks for your reply, Can you please tell me what modifications should be require in my above mentioned script for networking. If you have any script or steps please share with me.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: @SurajSharma:
Please read my comment under your question for things to check.
I don't think that the source of your problem is inside your script, if it works fine when connecting to Photon Cloud. So this is most likely an issue with the server configuration.

Comment: @SurajSharma:
You realize that you can just discuss this in the Photon developer forum at forum.photonengine.com, join the Photon Engine Discord or write an email to the address listed at https://www.photonengine.com/en-US/contact, do you?
Also you could always edit your stackoverflow question to add additional information like screenshots when it makes sense.